# Insert records into Google Bigquery from SQL server using Simba ODBC driver

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, odbc, linked-server, simba

I am using Simba ODBC driver to connect SQL server to Google Bigquery. While I am able to perform SELECT from Bigquery at SQL side, I am NOT able to INSERT into Bigquery from SQL.

This query works:

```
EXEC('insert into `rpm-dsi-datalabexchange.copytest.empty`(id, string) select 1, "abcdef"') at GOOGLEBQ
```

But all the below inserts returns the error - '*The requested operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "GOOGLEBQTEST" does not support the requested transaction interface.*'

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (GOOGLEBQ, 'select id from `rpm-dsi-datalabexchange.copytest.empty`')
values (12) 

insert openquery(GOOGLEBQ, 'select id, string from `rpm-dsi-datalabexchange.copytest.empty`')
select 1, '"ABCD"' 

BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
insert openquery(GOOGLEBQ, 'select id, lab from `rpm-dsi-datalabexchange.copytest.empty7`')
select 1, 'ABCD'
commit
```

Can anyone tell what could be the problem? I Have also attached the screenshots with the Linked Server settings.

[image: LinkedServerProperties]

[image: LinkedServerPropertiesAdvanced]

Comment: Might this shed some light:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/2948

I'm going to guess that, at this time, the BigQuery database doesn't support transactions (as alluded to in the link docs).

Comment: @Kolban I saw this too. But the Simba Magnitude guide says that DML statements are possible. Please check the chapter 'Features -> Write-back'. https://docs.rstudio.com/drivers/1.7.0/pdf/Simba%20Google%20BigQuery%20ODBC%20Connector%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf

Comment: I'll make some wild guesses here.  I agree that Simba seems to support DML statements ... however reading the Progress.com article, it seems to say that DML statements in this context execute within the context of transactions ... so it isn't DML it is DML PLUS Transactions.  Looking at the Simba docs ... and here is the guess ... try turning off transaction errors ... see the flag "IgnoreTransactions" and try and set that to "1" (or on).

Comment: @Kolban Could you please tell me how to set this flag if you know? I tried the command - 'SET IGNORETRANSACTIONS 1' in SQL but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: For your query regarding how to set the [flag](https://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/v2/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/options/ignoretransactions.htm) “IgnoreTransactions=1”, you can insert  the flag  “IgnoreTransactions=1” within your ODBC connection string and try to establish a connection.

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT Sorry for getting back so late. The Linked Server is installed via System DSN and not via a connection string. Is there a way to set this option in Sytem DSN?

Comment: Hi @DelinMathew, You can refer to this [document](https://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/v2/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/strings.htm) to know how to use connection string for a connection that uses a DSN.